# What is best practice to force form elements onto their own line, <p> or <div> element?

Tags: html, forms

I'm practicing creating an HTML form and was wondering whether a p tag or div tag would be best practice to set each form element on it's own line.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
<div>
    <label for="firstname">Enter your first name:</label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lastname">Enter your last name:</label>
    <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
```

Comment: Either one of them is fine but the `<p>` has some default styles while `<div>` doesn't. I personally prefer using `<fieldset>` and `<br>` or `<label>` with `display: block`

Comment: I'd rather use a <div>, just like you did. <p> stands for paragraph, so why use it for anything else than a paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<div>` or `<p>` use `<li>`s in an `<ol>` or `<ul>` *(if you need `<div>` or `<p>`, use `<div>` because it's more for interactivity than a paragraph)*